# Reading combobox data: Run time error '9'

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I'm trying to make a form to keep track of our Toner supply by using Excel to store the data.

I'm trying to call data from Excel by reading what is in 2 combo boxes.

When I run the Name combo box alone it works but when I run the model combo box I get error 9.

```vb
Private Sub cmbName_Change() 'User changed Name combo box
    VarRow = Worksheets("Printers").Columns(1).Find(What:=Me.cmbName.Text).Row
    Me.cmbModel.Text = Sheets("Printers").Cells(VarRow, 2).Value
End Sub

Private Sub cmbModel_Change() 'User changed Name or Model combo box
    VarRow = Worksheets("PrinterModels").Columns(1).Find(What:=Me.cmbModel.Text).Row
    Me.TBBlack.Text = Sheets("PrinterModels").Cells(VarRow, 2).Value
    Me.TBCyan.Text = Sheets("PrinterModels").Cells(VarRow, 3).Value
    Me.TBMagenta.Text = Sheets("PrinterModels").Cells(VarRow, 4).Value
    Me.TBYellow.Text = Sheets("PrinterModels").Cells(VarRow, 5).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the error description and which line did the error occur? You should set a variable to the result of `Find` and test if there is a match found first e.g. `Set findRng = Worksheets("PrinterModels").Columns(1).Find(What:=Me.cmbModel.Text)`, `If Not findRng Is Nothing Then [do something if found] Else [do something if not found]`

Comment: Error appears at VarRow in the second Sub

Comment: Also, some settings in `Find` method are persistent (namely LookIn, LookAt, SearchOrder, and MatchByte) so you should always specify those setting to avoid it finding in an unintended setting. [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find#:~:text=The%20settings%20for%20LookIn%2C%20LookAt%2C%20SearchOrder%2C%20and,explicitly%20each%20time%20you%20use%20this%20method.)

Comment: Are you sure you have a worksheet named `PrinterModels`? and not `PrinterModels `?

Comment: In the VBA Project window I have PrinterModels (Printer Models)

Comment: Try `Worksheets("Printer Models")` then, the argument given in `Worksheets` is the name of the worksheet, not the codename. Alternative I think you can refer to its codename by `PrinterModels.Columns(1)....`

Comment: Perfect! Looks like the Problem was I wasn't calling the Sheets as objects. But hey I've never done something like reviewing a sheet before so, you know.

Comment: Right, the problem was that you were referring to a worksheet that does not exist thus `Error 9: Subscript Out of Range`. Just to 
emphasize what braX and I had mentioned before - It is good practice to do a test first to check if the `Find` returns a match before doing anything with it. What you have in the question now can potentially generate a runtime error if there is no match found. @IanOberdorf

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Raymond Wu!

His comment below is the answer to my problem where I was incorrectly calling my sheets. When I ran PrinterModels.Columns(1) the error quit and the code funtioned as I wanted. Thanks again to all who commented!

"Try Worksheets("Printer Models") then, the argument given in Worksheets is the name of the worksheet, not the codename. Alternative I think you can refer to its codename by PrinterModels.Columns(1)."